# Sass content with slash

Tags: sass

I'm trying to minimize my sass and the character reference is screwing me up.

```
@each $name, $color, $code in ("info" "#286fad" "\e88f", "error" "#ad2828" "\e001") {
    .#{$name}-banner {
        background-color: $color;
        &:before {
            content: '#{$code}';
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is:

```css
content: "";
```

What I expect is:

```css
content: "\e88f";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with string interpolation using [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) until I found something that worked for this. Bit of a pain, but here you go!

```css
@each $name, $color, $code in (info #286fad e88f, error #ad2828 e001) {
    .#{$name}-banner {
        background-color: $color;
        &:before {
            content: #{'"\\' + $code + '"'};
        }
    }
}
```

...which resolves to:

```css
.info-banner { background-color: #286fad; }
.info-banner:before { content: "\e88f"; }

.error-banner { background-color: #ad2828; }
.error-banner:before { content: "\e001"; }
```

Comment: Thank You! Just started with sass yesterday.